# PHP regex split text to insert HTML

Tags: php, regex

Very(!) new to regex but...

I have the following text strings outputted from a $title variable:

```
A. This is a title
B. This is another title
```

etc...

I'm after the following:

```
<span>A.</span> This is a title
<span>B.</span> This is another title
```

etc...

Currently I have the following code:

```
$title = $element['#title'];
if (preg_match("([A-Z][\.])", $title)) {
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ">Blarg</li>\n";
} else {
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

This replaces anything A. through to Z. with Blarg however I'm not sure how to progress this?

In the Text Wrangler app I could wrap regex in brackets and output each argument like so:

```
argument 1 = \1
argument 2 = \2
```

etc...

I know I need to add an additional regex to grab the remainder of the text string.

Perhaps a regex guru could help and novice out!

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$title = 'A. This is a title';
$title = preg_replace('/^[A-Z]\./', '<span>$0</span>', $title);
echo $title;
// <span>A.</span> This is a title
```

If the string contains newlines and other titles following them, add the `m` modifier after the ending delimiter.

If the regex doesn't match then no replacements will be made, so there is no need for the `if` statement.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks ever so much. S

Answer (score 0):

Is it always just 2 char ("A.", "B.", "C.",...)
because then you could work with a substring instead of regex.
Just pick of the first 2 chars of the link and wrap the span around the substring

Comment: Though less robust, a perfectly valid thought - however it's best to provide a demonstration in your answer, not everyone's a pro ;)

Comment: Used regex solution above but thank you for coming back so quickly :-)

Comment: did not really have the time to make an example, but I'm glad you found a way to do whatever must be done ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
$title = $element['#title'];

if (preg_match("/([A-Z]\.)(.*)/", $title, $matches)) {
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . "><span>{$matches[0]</span>{$matches[1]}</li>\n";
} else {
  return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '>' . $output . $sub_menu . "</li>\n";
}
```

The change here was to first add `/` to the start and end of the string (to denote it's a regex), then remove the `[` and `]` around the period `.` because that's just a literal character on its own, then to add another grouping which will match the rest of the string. I also Added a `$matches` to `preg_match()` to place these two matches in to to use later, which we do on the next life.

**Note:** You could also do this instead:

```
$title = preg_replace('/^([A-Z]\.)/', "<span>$1</span>", $title);
```

This will simply replace the A-Z followed by the period at the start of the string (denoted with the `^` character) with `<span>`, that character (grabbed with the brackets) and `</span>`.

Again, that's not tested, but should give you a headstart :)

Comment: Thanks Leonard, used first answer but thanks for coming back so quickly :-)